# Multiple CountDown Timer running one after another

Tags: android, countdowntimer

this is my first question here.
I need to implement in my app six `countdown` `timers` running one after another. When first finishes, next one starts and so on. `Init time` of every single run depends on user input. The problem is that I need to put different code in `onTick()` and `onFinish()` methods for every single `countdown timer` running and, well, I'm not sure how to start a next `counter` after one is finished. I was thinking about calling next `counter` in `onFinish()` method of current one but I can't figure out how to do this with 6 `counters`.

This is my Countdown timer class:

```
public class Counter extends CountDownTimer
{

    public Counter(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval)
    {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
    {
            //this code is the same for every counter
            timer_view.setText(formatTime(millisUntilFinished));

            //this code depends on specific counter running
            output_view1.setText("My output here");
            output_view2.setText("My output here");
            output_view3.setText("My output here");

    }

    public void onFinish()
    {
        playSound(sound_id_1);
        runMyMethod(user_input_1);

        timerHasStarted = false;


    }

}
```

I'm starting my counter in the same activity:

```
if(!timerHasStarted)
{
counter = new Counter(user_input1, 1000);
    counter.start();
}
```

Comment: what you really want to achieve ?

Comment: I need to start multiple (6 in my case) countdown timers one after another. I think I found the way how - in fieldtech.io answer.
Now I need to figure out, how to put different code in onTick() method for every single countdown timer running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to break out the start timer functionallity and call it in `onFinish()`.

```
    public void startTimer(int counterId){
            Counter counter = null;
            switch(counterId){
                    case 0:
                            counter = new CounterOne(counterId,user_input1,1000);
                            break;  
                    /* Counter 1-5  goes here*/
                    default:
                            break;
            }
            if(counter !=null ){
                    counter.start();
            }
    }
```

then start your next timer in onFinsh()

```
    public abstract class Counter extends CountDownTimer
    {
            private int counterId;

            public Counter(int counterId /*counter id start with 0*/,long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval)
            {
                    super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
                    this.counterId = counterId;
            }

            public abstract void onTick(long millisUntilFinished);

            public void onFinish()
            {
                    playSound(sound_id_1);
                    runMyMethod(user_input_1);
                    startTimer(this.counterId++);
            }

    }

    public class CounterOne extends Counter{
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
            {
                    //counter 1 logic
            }
    }

    /* Subclass others. eg. CounterTwo etc. */
```

Comment: I like your idea. I'll try that. I think it should work for starting multiple countdown timers. Now I need to figure out, how to put different code in onTick() method..

Comment: well you can run diffrent code depending on the counterId. If this works for you(answers your question) please accept the answer. If not maybe you can elaborate on the specific problem you are trying to solve so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You never set

```
timerHasStarted
```

to true. It's always false, so...yeah, one timer after another. Set it to true before calling counter.start() and it should work.

Comment: I've pasted just a part of my code, my bad. It has been set. That's not an issue. I know how to start one single countdown timer, I just don't know how to set multiple (in my case 6) running one after another.