# How to display specific image from drawable based on specific characters of a String

Tags: android

I will try to describe my problem as clear as possible. I have an `ImageView` on a `fragment` and 3 `images`(labelled a,b,c) in `drawable` folder; I used `HashMap` to relate each image with their letters respectively. There is a String value with "bac". I converted this string to character array letter[] to get access to each individual letter. When function is called, it should insert `b.jpeg` first in to `ImageView`, after 10 Milliseconds delay, `ImageView` should be updated to `a.jpeg` then afterwards `c.jpeg`. Now problem is where it is only inserting last image which is `c.jpeg` in `ImageView` but I want `b.jpeg` to display first, then after delay `ImageView` should be updated with `a.jpeg` then `c.jpeg` respectively? How can I accomplish this in function below?

```
public void viewSign(){
  String value = "bac";

  final  Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    map.put("a", R.drawable.a);
    map.put("b", R.drawable.b);
    map.put("c", R.drawable.c);

    value = value.toLowerCase(); //stores "cricket!"
    char letter[] = value.toCharArray();

    for(int z=0;z<value.length();z++){

    switch (letter[z]) {
        case 'a':
            imageView5.setImageResource(map.get("a"));
            break;
        case 'b':
            imageView5.setImageResource(map.get("b"));
            break;
        case 'c':
            imageView5.setImageResource(map.get("c"));
            break;

        default:
    }
    try {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: 10ms is REALLY short. Are you sure that your program only show c.jpg? have u tried changing 10 to a higher duration, like 1000 and see whether b and a.jpg still not showing?

Comment: Yes when I increase to 1000. Still doesn't work.  Its just stuck for about 6 seconds then display c.jpeg. I think Runnable threads can help in this situation,  but how do I implement the logic?

Comment: @Kira can you write some logcat when the image change. then tell us does the logcat work correct or not

Comment: 05-04 23:41:05.497 23288-23288/com.example.vez.design3 D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2439K, 19% free 33080K/40492K, paused 24ms, total 26ms
05-04 23:41:05.537 23288-23288/com.example.vez.design3 D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 34K, 15% free 34646K/40492K, paused 21ms, total 21ms
05-04 23:41:05.567 23288-23288/com.example.vez.design3 I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 51.375MB for 14745616-byte allocation
05-04 23:41:06.678 23288-23288/com.example.vez.design3 D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1600K, 14% free 47447K/54896K, paused 46ms, total 47ms
05-04 23:41:06.718 23288-23288/com.example.v

Comment: I can tell you when I explicitly have this switch (letter[1]) , it does in fact sets imageview to a.jpeg. you can also see 3 delays in logs,

Answer (score 0):

Regarding `setImageResource(int)` from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource(int)

> This does Bitmap reading and decoding on the UI thread, which can cause a latency hiccup. If that's a concern, consider using setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) or setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap) and BitmapFactory instead.

Try changing your switch statements to this:

`imageView5.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(map.get("a"));`

Comment: Still doesn't work when I try Jonathan solution by switching statements,  but in log, it saying "the application may be doing too much work on its main thread"

Comment: How about trying `CountDownTimer`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

Comment: Seems like good idea; how do I implement this in function to match my own logic?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21555209/multiple-countdown-timer-running-one-after-another might have something that's relevant for you. use `setImageDrawable()` inside `onFinish()` of one `CountDownTimer`

Comment: Will research more and Ill try it out and will update you guys the outcome

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that your code really stops UI rendering  while viewSign() method is being executed. Every time time you call sleep(), it just pauses UI thread. So in the end just last drawable is being shown.

If you want them to appear un succession I would suggest using [postDelayed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)) method on your image view.

Something along the lines:

```
imageView5.postDelayed(new Runnable(){ imageView.setDrawable(..);}, 1000);
imageView5.postDelayed(new Runnable(){ imageView.setDrawable(..);}, 2000);
imageView5.postDelayed(new Runnable(){ imageView.setDrawable(..);}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 char[] letter;
Map<String, Integer> map
 public void viewSign(){
        String value = "bac";

      map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        map.put("a", R.drawable.a);
        map.put("b", R.drawable.b);
        map.put("c", R.drawable.c);

        value = value.toLowerCase(); //stores "cricket!"
        letter = value.toCharArray();

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                UpdateUI();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
            timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 10); 

    }
```

Her your UI update,

```
int arrayPosition = 0;
private void UpdateUI() {       
    if(letter.length>0){
         imageView5.setImageResource(map.get( String.valueOf(letter[arrayPosition])));
         arrayPosition++;
         if(letter.length == arrayPosition){
             arrayPosition = 0;//By reset the position, it will repeat the same process
         }
    }        
}
```

In the above code, I just try to match with your code, but you need to make the code efficient and error free.

Try this and let me know, i checked from my side its working fine.

Comment: Letter [] = value.toCharArray (); gave error, had to remove brackets,  but its not working,  no images is inserted in imageview

Comment: Just make that array global then only you can access it from UpdateUI method.(I added to implement by your own)

Comment: I made it global but in UpdateUI, I think image is not been set in image view.

Comment: by copying and pasting ur code, images are still not showing, idk whats problem

Comment: Edited my answer,. please check

Comment: Wow the transitions worked,  but im getting a huge lag and it's freezing,  when it made it to image c; but it did worked,  how do I fix lagging at end??

Comment: i didnt get you... lagging in loading the image third image?

Comment: Well lagging between images, as in I wud want it to transition more quickly through images,  also the app is very laggish, after it transit through 3 images.  Need this to be sorted out.

Comment: Thank you all guys for responses,  im really relieved I got this to work.  Will help immensely.  (Y)

Answer (score 0):

Hey kira when your application hits this line  `TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(10);` your main thread gets into the sleep state hence the latency.
Also your main thread logic is never executed until for loop is completed and last image is set.
only after your function returns the control image is drawn.
Here is the code that will help you.

```
    final  Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        map.put("a", R.drawable.a);
        map.put("b", R.drawable.b);
        map.put("c", R.drawable.c);
    value = value.toLowerCase(); //stores "cricket!"
    char letter[] = value.toCharArray();
  Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
                    public void run() {


                           for(int z=0;z<letter.length;z++){

    switch (letter[z]) {

        case 'a':
           imageid = map.get("a");//this variable is instance variable of class not local variable
            break;
        case 'b':
            imageid = map.get("b");
            break;
        case 'c':
             imageid = map.get("c");
            break;

        default:
    }
                            imageView5.post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                   imageView5.setImageResource(imageid);
                                }
                            });
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(1000);
                            } catch (InterruptedExeption e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
thread.start();
```

Comment: Wats Imageid here in code, and im getting errors in your code

Comment: its integer variable

Comment: if you use post delayed app response will be laggy

Comment: You are genius,  your solution works perfectly,  with no lags. @srinivasan did also worked but lagging was problem.  You explained it pretty well. THANK YOU SO MUCH :). THIS WILL HELP ME DEVELOP MY APP FOR FINAL YEAR PROJECT. (Y)

Comment: thanx for the compliment